# how can we identify the novel protein amino acid sequence and function?

Tags: biochemistry, amino-acids

if there is a novel protein, how would you know the amino acid sequence and  how would you determine the number of subunits and the function of that protein?

Specifically what molecular techniques we can use to identify the novel protein?

Basically, this is a question asked during a biochemistry interview? It will be helpful, if someone just clarify it

Comment: What do you know about the protein?

Comment: This is very broad and sounds like a [homework question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). In any case you should show what attempts you have made to find an answer yourself.